# How do I use ActiveMQ Blob messages?

Tags: java, struts2, activemq-classic

Has anyone tried sending ActiveMQ Blob messages?

I am having trouble uploading images to a webapp through AMQ Blob messages.  I followed their documentation ( http://activemq.apache.org/blob-messages.html ).  I set the Upload URL to be the url i wanted the files to go (ie: http://localhost:8080/myapp/uploads) and i keep getting an exception: `javax.jms.JMSException: PUT was not successful: 404 Not Found.`

Has anyone else experienced this?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

I am using: ActiveMQ 5.3.0 and Struts 2.1.8.1 (for my web framework)

**Edit** : When setting the blob transfer policy on the session, i was getting a 404 Not Found exception.  When changing it to the activemq connection, i am now getting a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: hi getting the same issue can somebody help please

Answer (score 0):

you have to use http://localhost:8080/myapp/uploads/
dont forget the "/" ;)